# How to manipulate javascript script attribute

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
<script id="lol" type="text/javascript" src="http://pn.lol.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=999999&produkt=7&umsatz=0&kunde=raffle_201406&js=1"></script>
```

I want the tid of the ´src´attribute to be a random number and not 999999, so I wrote a script before it which tries to change it:

```
<script>
   var transactionId = Math.floor(Math.random()  * 100000); //Generate pseudorandom id
   var element = document.getElementById("lol");
   var newsrc = "http://pn.lol.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=" + transactionId + "&produkt=7&umsatz=0&kunde=raffle_201406&js=1";
   element.setAttribute("src", newsrc);

</script>
```

But that does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

What I want to have is the following code but with random tid parameter on the src:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pn.lol.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=t26673&produkt=Raffle201406&umsatz=1&kunde=raffle_201406&js=1"></script>
<noscript><img  src="http://pn.lol.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=t26673&produkt=Raffle201406&umsatz=1&kunde=raffle_201406" height="3" width="2" border="0" /></noscript>
```

So I wrote the following:

```
<script>

   var transactionId = Math.floor(Math.random()  * 100000); //Generate pseudorandom id
   var element = document.createElement('script');//Create new script element
   var newsrc = "http://pn.lol.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=" + transactionId + "&produkt=Raffle201406&umsatz=0&kunde=raffle_201406&js=1";
   element.setAttribute("src", newsrc);
   element.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");

   var elementNoscript = document.createElement('noscript');//Create new script element
   var elementImg = document.createElement('img');
   elementImg.setAttribute("src",newsrc);
   elementImg.setAttribute("height",3);
   elementImg.setAttribute("width",2);
   elementImg.setAttribute("border",0);

   document.body.appendChild( element ); // Insert it into document
   elementNoscript.appendChild(elementImg);
   document.body.appendChild( elementNoscript );

</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to work, any idea where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure a tid of the value you generate is valid according to pn.lol.de 's API ??

Comment: `#lol` doesn't exist at the time you try to use it, (even if it would, you can't change the script once it is loaded.) This is not possible. You have to create the attribute on server-side, or load the script dynamically.

Comment: @paradoxyes tid  is correct, I am sure about that. I was thinking if it is a better way to add something random in the script without using another script

Comment: You can't reload scripts like that. You have to make a new element with new src then append to body.

Comment: @Avraam If this script is within `head`, `body` doesn't exist at the time you try to append a new element. Try to append to `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` instead of `body`. `noscript` must be appended to `body`. You've to separate the task into two parts or move all the script to the `body`.

Answer (score 3):

I would dynamicaly insert script element instead of changing src property of already existing one. This should work for sure:

```
<script>

   var transactionId = Math.floor(Math.random()  * 100000); //Generate pseudorandom id

   var element = document.createElement('script');//Create new script element
   var newsrc = "http://pn.discavo.de/get_trans.cgi?cpid=1&tid=" + transactionId + "&produkt=7&umsatz=0&kunde=raffle_201406&js=1";
       element.setAttribute("src", newsrc);
   document.body.appendChild( element ); // Insert it into document


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, hurried a little there.

Comment: @Avraam Notice, that dynamically added scripts are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: @Teemu can be this the reason that my script is not seem to run?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='New JS Likns';
```